# I am getting error while login in google via firebase auth

Tags: android, firebase, google-authentication

I am using firebase authentication for sign in into app through google but when I clicked on sign in button list of account appear but after choosing an account nothing happens. in logs, I am getting API exception 7

Error Logs :

```
    2019-08-01 16:48:30.591 5073-5073/rishab.listview.com.stepcounter W/google sign in failed: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 7: 
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(Unknown Source:8)
    at rishab.listview.com.stepcounter.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:184)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7276)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4264)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4312)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1644)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Update google libraries to their latest?

Comment: I have created a [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseApp) in which I have implemented Firebase Authentication using a Google account. Might solve your problem.

Comment: please provide code. and are you using a phone or an emulator to run your code?

Comment: Have you done all the steps : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin